# Extend from 3 hour slot to N days

Tags: c++, algorithm, function

I want to set up *params.arrival_rate* every 3 hours of sim_time. This comprises a day but I would like to extend to N days. So, each time slot of 3 hours (in the code below is in minutes) of this N day, *params.arrival_rate* takes a value. Any optimal function to do so?

My actual code looks like this:

```
    if(sim_time >= 0 && sim_time <= 180) //00:00 - 03:00 
    {
        params.arrival_rate = 10; 
    }
    else if(sim_time > 180 && sim_time <= 360) //03:00-06:00
    {
        params.arrival_rate = 9; 
    }
    else if(sim_time > 360 && sim_time <= 540) //06:00-09:00 
    {
        params.arrival_rate = 10.5; 
    }
    else if(sim_time > 540 && sim_time <= 720) //09:00-12:00
    {
        params.arrival_rate = 12; 
    }
    else if(sim_time > 720 && sim_time <= 900) //12:00-15:00 
    {
        params.arrival_rate = 11.5; 
    }
    else if(sim_time > 900 && sim_time <= 1080) //15:00-18:00 
    {
        params.arrival_rate = 11; 
    }
    else if(sim_time > 1080 && sim_time <= 1260) //18:00-21:00 
    {
        params.arrival_rate = 10.5; 
    }
    else if(sim_time > 1260 && sim_time <= 1440) //21:00-24:00   
    {
        params.arrival_rate = 9;
    }
    else //by default 
    {
        params.arrival_rate = 9;   
    }
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Why this constants are multiple of 4320 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the same pattern every day, it suffices to take the time modulo 1440 minutes:

```
int day_time = sim_time % 1440;
int day_no   = sim_time / 1440;
```

Now you can use `day_time` to get the time in the current day and use that to calculate `params.arrival_rate`. `day_no` will contain the day number (starting from 0).

As a further enhancement, consider using an array for your arrival rates instead of a long if-elseif chain:

```
const double arrival_rates[] = { 10, 9, 10.5, 12, 11.5, 11, 10.5, 9 };
params.arrival_rate = arrival_rates[day_time / (3 * 60)];
```

The calculation inside the brackets will round down the day_time to the start of the nearest three-hour block.

Comment: Many thanks! Your answer is very useful. But, why do you do modulo and divide sim_time by 86400. This is the day in seconds and my simulator time is in minutes. Should be by 1440? Thanks again :)

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry. It never occurred to me that people would simulate things in minute increments. Will edit my answer.

Comment: It does not work as expected. params.arrival_rate does not change its value each 3 hour-block.

Comment: Now I'm totally confused. 4320 minutes is 3 days, not 3 hours. Shouldn't that be 180 minutes instead?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I took the minutes wrong. I correct my question. Now, your answer is right!